# Listview not showing long subitem

Tags: vb.net

I have come across a strange issue, i have to store soem values in a listview, the 5th column (index 4) is a **very long** string:

```
For Each itm As ListViewItem In listViewShowLinks.CheckedItems

MessageBox.Show(itm.SubItems(4).Text.Trim())

Next
```

When i try to messagebox show the string to use, it's coming up blank even though the string is physically there, the other values show fine, i assume it's to do with the length of the value, is there a way i can show the value? i need to pass it to another form.

cheers for any help guys!

Graham

Comment: The problem is not the length of the string but the string it self. Probably **there isn't** any string to print. How long is the string anyway?

Comment: I have to say the string is pretty long! it definatelty exists and is visible in the listview: http://i.imgur.com/sdaBsSQ.jpg (small preview of it) it's very strange!

Comment: I removed the string cause is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use a list box in a winfom  to show content of your string. list box automatically give the vertical scroll bar if string goes beyond the listbox size.

Comment: Hi Mate, although i can see the value in the listview, when i try to print it to screen it shows blank! i cannot figure it out lol

Comment: Message box have limit (1024) to number of character it can show. probably you string size is bigger than this. you can test it easily. MessageBox.Show(itm.SubItems(4).Text.Trim().Substring(0, 1000)) . if it is printing , it means it is issue with length of string.

Comment: hmm just tried  MessageBox.Show(itm.SubItems(4).Text.Substring(0, 1000)) which still shows blank lol the other values which are regular few digits show fine aswell.